# Asp.net-mvc: Calling Session_Start in global.asax

Tags: c#, session, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using visual studio 2015 and asp.net mvc and I want to initialize a session variable in the Session Start method but im not sure about the signature of the method and i couldn't find documentation about it

Here is what i have as of now in my global.asax file :

```
 public void Session_Start()
    {
        InscriptionPaiementEntities dbm = new InscriptionPaiementEntities();
        var NbreItemMax = dbm.INSC_config.Where(p => p.NomParametre == 
         "NbreItemMax").FirstOrDefault();
        Session["NbreItemMax"] = NbreItemMax.Texte;
    }
```

Any Help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: It dosen't seem to call the function I have checked with the debugger and I think that its maybe because the signature is wrong. Maybe I should use protected or add some parameters ?

Comment: The signature of the method is `protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust the method signature.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   InscriptionPaiementEntities dbm = new InscriptionPaiementEntities();
   var NbreItemMax = dbm.INSC_config.Where(p => p.NomParametre == 
         "NbreItemMax").FirstOrDefault();
   Session["NbreItemMax"] = NbreItemMax.Texte;
}
```

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier great. Please mark the question as answered if it solved your problem, so that others can benefit from it as well.